# Exact format of JIRA smart commits

Tags: git, jira, atlassian-fisheye

I've read through:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-298976812.html

And I understand how a commit message like:

```
This is the subject line

This is the body. There might be several lines here
as per good git commit message formatting.

ABC-1234 #close All fixed
```

Would close the jira issue `ABC-1234` with the message "All fixed".

But what is the exact format required for these smart commits to work? Would a line in a commit message like the following work:

```
[ABC-1234] #close All fixed
```

What about a line that doesn't start with the `ISSUE_KEY`, would the following work:

```
Jira-Smart-Commit: ABC-1234 #close All fixed
```

Is there some place I could get an exact definition of what will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the format for a smart commit is as follows

```
  <ignored text> <ISSUE_KEY> <ignored text> #<COMMAND> <optional COMMAND_ARGUMENTS>
```

so you dont need to put the issue key at the start of the line.

We are currently in the process of revamping the documentation, so you may find more information there than the last time you look

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+smart+commits

Comment: How can I open a new issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax:**

```
<ignored text> ISSUE_KEY <ignored text> #comment <comment_string>
Changes for JIRA Id LOANDEV-165320 #comment:Initial Commit for Employee Project
```

[reference here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-960155400.html)

Comment: Is the other answer insufficient?